# building skeleton from fbx model

Tags: animation, three.js, fbx

I am trying to export an armature from blender as an FBX file and then constructing a skeleton out of it once loaded using the FBXLoader. Then, I want to merge it with a skinned mesh character. My goal is to have different models and different poses and to just be able to mix and match between them.

I attempted to create a codepen of it here: https://codepen.io/michael-tipton/pen/mGvvQr?editors=0011 1
but the fbxloader isn’t pulling the files from dropbox. Unsure how to proceed there.

My main function for creating the bones from the FBX file is as follows:

```
function createBones( root , array ) {
            if(root === null && root === undefined ) {
              return;
            } else {
              let bone = new THREE.Bone();

              bone.position.set( root.position.x, root.position.y, root.position.z );
              bone.name = root.name;
              bone.setRotationFromQuaternion( root.quaternion );
              bone.scale.set( root.scale.x, root.scale.y, root.scale.z );
              if(root.parent !== null && root.parent !== undefined ) {
                  bone.parent = root.parent;
              }
              array.push(bone);

              for(let i = 0, count = root.children.length; i < count; i++) {
                  createBones(root.children[i], array);
              }
              return;
            }
        }
```

I’m having a hard time figuring out how to go about troubleshooting. I attempted to use skeletonhelper but the armature is so warped and different than the model (and also extremely small) that it isn’t particularly helpful in letting me know what is going on.

I’m not sure if the armature isn’t loading correctly or if I’m not recreating the skeleton correctly, or if it is something else. When I tried applying some sort of movement to the armature, the skinnedmesh didn’t move at all.

Does anyone have experience with troubleshooting these types of issues or have any ideas how I can get insight into what is going on? Thanks and 1 million karma credits to you for reading this!

Comment: I get error: Failed to load https://www.dropbox.com/s/9z0vmuwemq17lu5/Pose3.fbx?dl=0: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. ___ You got that two right??

Comment: Interesting.  This appears to be a CORS issue.  I think this can be addressed by appending auth data to the URL, but not sure yet.  Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: The cors issue was just one of many... I'm sending you a formal answer to break down the issues

Answer (score 0):

First I noticed I was getting flooded with messages in the console, so I commented your console.log from the animate:

```
var animate = function() {
  const v = Date.now() / 2000
  var hips = scene.getObjectByName("hips");
  if (hips) {
    hips.position.x = Math.sin(v) * 10
    hips.position.z = Math.cos(v) * 10
  }
  //console.log(hips);
}
```

That's when I noticed the CORS issue so downloaded the files locally.
Then I got an error about a missing library (`inflate.min.js`) downloaded that and added to the project.

Here is your code in a "works for me" with no more console errors:  
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/html/HTML/bones/bones.html

Comment: this is really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I plus one’d but it doesn’t give credit since I have below 15 rep :(